# Our video(website is bootstrap) isn't positioned on center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here's our website: http://www.ylandria.hu

There's a little problem: It's working well, except iPads. On iPads, the video is on the left side instead of center.

Because the website is created with bootstrap, and we can't rebuild that, we don't know any solutions.

How can we change it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with bootstrap. You need to learn more about Responsive Web design (RWD) and media queries.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

To start with, check bootstrap's column model of your code.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_small.asp

If that doesn't work, put your video in a div container, do a media-query and accordingly put alignment styles to your div container.

Also, I checked your website, avoid having height and width of the video element as fixed. Have it in percentage.

You need to be better at asking questions at this forum. Be precise and post code.

Let me know if you need more links on this.

Cheers!